# nbytes and getsizeof return different values

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I have noticed that `nbytes` and `getsizeof` returns two different values when the bank to a NumPy array.

Example:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(10000, 50)
print('x.nbytes: {0} bytes'.format(x.nbytes))
print('sys.getsizeof(x): {0} bytes'.format(sys.getsizeof(x)))
```

Output:

```
x.nbytes: 4000000 bytes
sys.getsizeof(x): 4000112 bytes
```

Why?

Comment: Overhead - shape, strides, dtype etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because `nbytes` only returns the size of stored data, while `sys.getsizeof` returns the size of the whole object, i.e. the size of the stored data plus some overhead. There is a small overhead for numpy arrays, because they have to store the array dimensions, the datatype and similar information.