# Why is each element in a sparse csc matrix 8 bytes?

Tags: python, matrix, memory, storage

For example, if I initially have a dense matrix:

```
A = numpy.array([[0, 0],[0, 1]])
```

and then convert it to a csc sparse matrix using csc_matrix(A). The matrix is then stored as:

```
(1, 1)    1
#(row, column)   val
```

which comprises of three values. Why is the size of the sparse matrix only 8 bytes, even though the computer is essentially storing 3 values? Surely the size of the matrix would be a least 12 bytes, since an integer usually holds 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree that the size of the sparse matrix is 8 bytes. I may be missing something, but if I do this, I get a very different answer:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import numpy
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> A = numpy.array([[0, 0],[0, 1]])
>>> s = sparse.csc_matrix(A)
>>> s
<2x2 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>
>>> sys.getsizeof(s)
56
```

This is the size of the data structure in memory and I assure you that it is accurate. Python must know how big it is, because it does the memory allocation.

If, on the other hand, you use `s.data.nbytes`:

```
>>> s.data.nbytes       
4
```

This gives the expected answer of 4. It is expected because `s` reports itself as having one stored element of type `int32`. The value returned, according to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nbytes.html),

> does not include memory consumed by non-element attributes of the array object.

This is not a more accurate result, just an answer to a different question, as [35421869](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421869/nbytes-and-getsizeof-return-different-values) makes clear.

I can't explain why you report a value of 8 bytes when the result 4 is clearly correct. One possibility is that `numpy.array([[0, 0],[0, 1]])` is not in fact what was actually converted to the sparse array. Where did the value 5 come from? The value of 8 is consistent with a beginning value of `numpy.array([[0, 0],[0, 5.0]])`.

Your figure of 12 bytes is based on two unmet expectations.

1. It is *possible* to represent a sparse matrix as a list of triples *(row, column, value)*. And that is in fact how a COO-matrix is stored, at least in principle. But CSC stands for *compressed sparse column* and so there are fewer explicit column indexes than in a COO-matrix. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) provides a lucid explanation of how the storage actually works.
2. `nbytes` does not report the total memory cost of storing the elements of the matrix. It reports a `numpy` invariant (over many different kinds of matrix) `x.nbytes == np.prod(x.shape) * x.itemsize`. This is an important quantity because the explicitly stored elements of the matrix form its biggest subsidiary data structure and must be allocated in contiguous memory.

Comment: I'm using .data.nbytes which I feel is a more accurate representation of memory.
So s.data.nbytes would give 8 bytes in total

Comment: My mistake, the 5 is meant to be a 1.
I've checked the code again and it turns out I'm using float values instead of integers, which explains why it gives 8 bytes instead of 4.

However, my question still stands. If it is storing the integer value 1, as well as its row and column indexes (1, 1), surely the storage should be greater than 4 bytes?

Comment: No, the row and column are not *elements* and so are not included,  as the documentation says. They are part of the sparse array metadata, and live in the 56-byte structure.