# nbytes and getsizeof return different values after reshaping

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This question is related to the one here: [nbytes and getsizeof return different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421869/nbytes-and-getsizeof-return-different-values)

I tested the same amount of data in a numpy array and got different (by a lot) `getsizeof` values when I reshape. You'll find below the code I tested.

```
from sys import getsizeof
import numpy as np

test_array = np.asarray(np.arange(1000000.0)).reshape(1000, 1000)
print("Real size of test array is {:,.0f}".format(getsizeof(test_array)))
print("NP size of test array is {:,.0f}".format(test_array.nbytes))
```

Result:

```
Real size of test array is 112
NP size of test array is 8,000,000
```

Without reshaping,

```
from sys import getsizeof
import numpy as np

test_array = np.asarray(np.arange(1000000.0))
print("Real size of test array is {:,.0f}".format(getsizeof(test_array)))
print("NP size of test array is {:,.0f}".format(test_array.nbytes))
```

I get:

```
Real size of test array is 8,000,096
NP size of test array is 8,000,000
```

Comment: Read about numlpy views.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/52897457/901925

Comment: Thank you hpaulj!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy Matrix Memory size low compared to Numpy Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897457/numpy-matrix-memory-size-low-compared-to-numpy-array)